# How many particles can a cyclotron accelerate per accelerating cycle?

Tags: acceleration, particle-accelerators

What is the limit for how many particles can be accelerated in a batch per one accelerating cycle by a cyclotron /size of gap between D's?/?
I've found [simillar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224105/how-many-particles-can-a-particle-accelerator-accelerate-at-once) - the answer was refering to the LHC, however, stating 300 trillion particles per beam?

Comment: Googling 'cyclotron beam current' pulls up a variety of material from, particularly, CERN and the US Particle Accelerator School, that are relevant. Do you mean particles in one bunch, or in all bunches?

Comment: Hi @Jon Custer, thanks for the fast reply. The results from Google give the output energy and power consumption. I mean particles in all bunches per one accelerating cycle. For example, the accelerating process with TRIMF takes approximately 0.3 ms - but how many particles are accelerated for that period? The article says proton but I think they mean the whole beam, so how ''big'' is that beam? https://www.triumf.ca/research-program/research-facilities/main-cyclotron-beam-lines

Comment: Triumf claims 1000 trillion protons per second, in 3000 bunches per second emerging from the machine. What I can't find is how many times a bunch goes around the cyclotron before emerging, but that could be ~300, so there are ~100 trillion particles in the machine at various stages of getting accelerated.

Comment: Hey Jon, ''Triumf claims 1000 trillion protons per second, in 3000 bunches per second emerging from the machine.'' - can you share the link to the article?

Comment: https://www.triumf.ca/home/about-triumf/about-us/faq-about-triumf/triumf-backgrounder

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jon!